# Выборка из mysql в виде двумерного массива

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот есть такой запрос:

```
Select `u`.`name`, `i`.`url`, `i`.`title`, `i`.`likes`
From `users` as `u`
Left join `images` as `i`
On `u`.`image_id` = `i`.`id`
Where `users`.`id` = 5
```

Мне нужен массив, чтобы работать с ним в php примерно в таком виде:

```
$data['name']
$date['image']['url']
$data['image']['title']
$data['image']['likes']
```

Можно ли сделать это средствами mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Средствами mysql этого не сделать. Все превращение структуры данных нужно делать на сторона PHP. И на сколько я понял, структура данных должна быть такая

```
    [
        'name1' => 
            [
                'url1' => ['title' => '...', 'likes' => 5],
                'url2' => ['title' => '...', 'likes' => 10]
            ],
        'name2' =>
            [
                'url3' => ['title' => '...', 'likes' => 3],
                'url4' => ['title' => '...', 'likes' => 7]
            ],
    ]
```

Вот такой код превратит результат запроса в нужную вам струкутуру

```
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data[$row['name']][$row['url']] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'likes' => $row['likes']];
    }
```

Comment: ок. печаль что средствами mysql не сделать. отрицательный ответ тоже ответ)